# How can I simplify a jQuery condition?

Tags: jquery

I have an OR condition that checks if any of two checkboxes are checked, it works great but I am wondering if there are some other ways of implementing this to simplify code...

It would be great if this can be done with defining `private` class in a varibale.
    `forum_private = $('.private').first().prop("checked") || $('.private').last().prop("checked")`

I tried with `forum_private = $('.private').filter(':checked')` but this doesn't works.

Comment: Ok, so there will be:
`private = $('.private')
forum_private = private.first().prop("checked") || private.last().prop("checked")`

Comment: not sure if you can put this in a var but you could do `if ($(".private:first:checked, .private:last:checked").length)`

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the statement as

```
$('.private:first:checked, .private:last:checked').length >= 1
```